# Django suspicious file operation

Tags: python, django, package, virtualenv

I have made a django package with templates and a static file that I installed in a different django project. When I run the function that calls the installed package it gives me this error:

> SuspiciousFileOperation at /test/render
> The joined path (/static/images/logo.png) is located outside of the base path component (/mnt/c/Users/user/Work/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static)
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/test/render
> Django Version: 4.0.4
> Exception Type: SuspiciousFileOperation
> Exception Value:
> The joined path (/static/images/logo.png) is located outside of the base path component (/mnt/c/Users/user/Work/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static)

I tried several different approaches to this issue, but none have worked out for me. I tried collectstatic but nada. I have added my package to the installed_apps so that the staticfiles.finders can serve the static but still nothing.

Here are my static settings:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'
]
```

Has someone else encountered this issue or have any advice for this problem? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I think that the problem is occurring because it is trying to reach out to a package inside of the env which has the main static file, and the env is outside the BASE_DIR. At least this is what I think as of this moment.

Answer (score 0):

use `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL)` and don't forget to add `import os` at the last line of your settings.

Comment: I have tried this, it still gives me the exact same error.

Comment: Add to the last line of setting. And if the error still exists, print(STATIC_ROOT) after this line and put the value here. The value most point to your project's root directory.

Comment: So, using: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL)
I still get the error:  [03/Jun/2022 13:23:13] ERROR [django.security.SuspiciousFileOperation:124] The joined path (/static/images/logo.png) is located outside of the base path component (/mnt/c/Users/user/Work/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static)